# Can the integral $\int^\infty_0 \frac{du}{(1+u^p)(1+u) }$ be computed only with contour integration method?

Tags: integration

Can the follwing integral be computed only with contour integration ?$p>0$ $$\int^\infty_0 \frac{du}{(1+u^p)(1+u) }$$
One of my questions turned out to calculate this integral I am not familiar with contour integration  to find it. I am wondering if there is any other method,for p=-0.5,0.5,1,2,3,4 I could find it by decompositiob methodl.

Comment: contour integration

Comment: Yes, it can. For example, thee command of Maple simplify(int(1/((u^4 + 1)*(1 + u)), u = 0 .. infinity, method = contour)); performs $$-1/4\,{\frac {\pi\,\sqrt {2} \left( \sqrt {2}-4 \right) }{ \left( -2+
\sqrt {2} \right) ^{2} \left( 2+\sqrt {2} \right) ^{2}}}
 .$$

Comment: @user64494 Which simplifies to $\frac{\pi(2\sqrt{2}-1)}{8}$.

Comment: The integral is not elementary for general $p > 0$, it gives the Fox H-function
$$H_{2, 2}^{2, 2} {\left(1 \middle|
 {(0, 1), (0, p) \atop (0, 1), (0, p)} \right)}.$$

Comment: @Maxim. Could you provide me the Mathematica syntax for the above expression ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is an integer, a CAS finds explicit solutions such as
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \int^\infty_0 \frac{du}{(1+u^p)(1+u) }\\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & \frac{\pi }{4} \\
 3 & \frac{1}{3}+\frac{2 \pi }{9 \sqrt{3}} \\
 4 & \frac{1}{8} \left(2 \sqrt{2}-1\right) \pi \\
 5 & \frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{25} \sqrt{5-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}} \pi \\
 6 & \frac{1}{72} \left(30-8 \sqrt{3}\right) \pi
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $p > 6$, it does not seem possible to get an explicit result.

If $p$ is the half of an integer, the only results I have been able to obtain are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \int^\infty_0 \frac{du}{(1+u^p)(1+u) }\\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\pi }{2} \\
 \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{18} \left(-9+8 \sqrt{3}\right) \pi  \\
 \frac{5}{2} & \frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{4}{5} \sqrt{1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}} \pi  
\end{array}
\right)$$

If $p$ is the third of an integer, the only results I have been able to obtain are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{3} & 1+\frac{2 \pi }{3 \sqrt{3}} \\
 \frac{4}{3} & \frac{1}{24} \left(9+18 \sqrt{2}-16 \sqrt{3}\right) \pi  
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: For integers $p>6$, it is indeed possible to get explicit results in some sense.

If $p=2n, n$ integer $\ge 1$ then the value of the integral is
\begin{equation*}
 -\dfrac{\pi}{8n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(2k+1)\tan\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{4n}\right)
\end{equation*}
 If $p=2n-1, n$ integer $\ge 1$ then the value of the integral is
\begin{gather*}
\dfrac{1}{2n-1} -\dfrac{\pi}{2(2n-1)^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(2k+1)\tan\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2(2n-1)}\right)-\\ 
\dfrac{\pi}{2(2n-1)^2}\sum_{k=n}^{2n-2}(2k+1)\tan\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2(2n-1)}\right)
\end{gather*}